# What follows words like "allow" or "require"?

Tags: grammar

Which of these is more appropriate and why:

"allow to change something" or "allow changing something"

"require filling it in" or "require to fill it in"

Comment: We really need the rest of the sentence here to judge: there's also the option of "*allowed* to change something"/"*required* to fill it in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an infinitive, the transitive version of *allow* takes a subject together with the infinitive as the object of *allow*. In other words, the following is correct:
*The new law allows people to smoke outside.* (Correct)
Notice the word *people* as the subject of *to smoke*.
The following is not correct:
*The new law allows to smoke outside.* (Incorrect)
This incorrect version is very common in non-native English speakers.
To correct the second version, we change the infinitive *to smoke* into a gerund, *smoking*:
*The new law allows smoking outside.* (Correct)

Answer (score 0):

All of the variants above can be right in differing contexts.

As a general rule, there are two different constructions based on what you would like to emphasize:

allow/require + gerund (This provides a blanket, impersonal statement)

> The college does not allow smoking on campus.

allow/require + someone + infinitive (more specific, personal statement)

> He never allows his students to cheat during exams.

More details can be found in nearly any grammar resource. I would recommend Michael Swan's [Practical English Usage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0194420981).

Comment: Can the second version be used without additional words? As in "He never allows to cheat during exams"? It seems strange to me.

Comment: Not in that form...it would have to be "he never allows cheating during exams".

Comment: @KristinaLopez But it seems to work sometimes: "It helps to try again in case of failure."

Comment: @Anonymous20DB28 Can you give any examples? Your quoted sentence isn’t connected with allow/require.

Comment: It doesn't use 'allow' or 'require' but I don't know what the general class of words here is and if 'help' is in it or not.